# How to query only values that show up in the database more than once

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do a market-basket analysis for sales data. For this, I need two values, `order_id` and `product_id`.

I only want the `order_id` and the `product_id` when there are duplicate values of each not necessarily in the same row, but I don't want to get rid of those values, I want to get rid of the order_id and product_id if they only show in the database once. It should be ordered by `order_id`. The result should look something like this

from this

| order_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 |

to this

| order_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

```
SELECT order_id, product_id
FROM order_items
ORDER BY order_id
```

Comment: There are no duplicate rows in your data though, and your attempt has a 3rd column, but you don't want that in your data. What you explain, and the data you expect don't match.

Comment: sorry, I don't want the third column it was just something I attempted. I didn't mean duplicate rows, I just meant duplicate values. I only want to see the order_id that is also in other rows, the same as the product_id

Comment: If you just want all the rows, why do you have a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`?

Comment: i'm new to SQL, it is just something I tried, I thought I would put it in but probably shouldn't have

Comment: i want to get rid of the product_id and order_id that is only in the database once

Comment: So you want to filter out all those rows, as none of the rows in that dataset fultil the requirement of having 2 rows that are the same. I suggest you take the time to provide both sample data and expected results and better explain the problem using the [edit] feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is a far more elegant solution, but if I understand your question to want rows that have either an order_id or product_id that shows up more than once in the DB, then I believe this will work:

**EDIT:**
If you need them both to have multiple items in the list then I would just individually join them to a subquery as such:

```
SELECT t1.order_id, t1.product_id
FROM order_items  t1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ORDER_ID from order_items  group by ORDER_ID having count(*) > 1) t2 
    ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT PRODUCT_ID from order_items  group by PRODUCT_ID having count(*) > 1) t3 
    ON t1.product_id = t3.product_id
ORDER BY order_id
```

Comment: if a product_id or order_id shows up only once I want them gone from the results

Answer (score 1):

A couple of windowed aggregates would probably work best™ here:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT order_id,
           product_id,
           COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) AS orders,
           COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) AS products
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT order_id,
       product_id
FROM CTE
WHERE orders > 1
  AND products > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` keyword can make the query simpler, but I'm not sure about the performance...

```sql
select order_id, product_id from order_items
where order_id not in (
  select order_id from order_items group by order_id having count(*) = 1
) and product_id not in (
  select product_id from order_items group by product_id having count(*) = 1
);
```